# Best practice for application.properties for tests in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I have seen projects where a standalone `application.properties` is defined under `src/test/resources` containing all the properties from the default `application.properties` defined under `src/main/resources` while overriding properties for testing purposes. The disadvantage of this approach is that every change (adding/removing/updating of properties) must be done in both application.properties, otherwise tests *may* fail.

On the other hand I have seen projects where only a context based property file is defined under `src/test/resources`, say `application-test.properties` containing only the overriden properties for testing purposes. This approach merges the default `application.properties` under `src/main/resources` and the `application-test.properties` under `src/test/resources`. The respective context must be activated in test classes via `@ActiveProfiles`, say `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

What is the approach you follow and why? Is there any best practice or recommendation for this?

Thanks for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Profiles are generally used to "map" different Spring beans accordingly. I've seen that people usually stick to three of them for most of the workflows: `development`, `test`, and `production` — mainly in tutorials and blogs.

I use profiles aligned with the actual environments the application is going to be deployed at since it's more realistic. So I always run the tests with the `local` profile. If I need any specific settings for running the tests, I just redefine an `application.properties` file under `src/test/resources` and overwrite what's needed.

In this way, you would always effectively have what's going to be used to run the application in each environment within `src/main/resources`, and if anything needs to be overwritten **only for testing**, the `src/test/resources/application.properties` could take care of that.

For instance, let's say your `src/main/resources/application.yaml` file looks like:

```yaml
application:
  key: value-common
  another-key: value-common-another
spring:
  profiles:
    active: default
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  main:
    banner-mode: console
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
```

This defines *effectively* two profiles: `local` and `test` — because `default` would have what's common to both. Now, if you place an `application.properties` file with the following content in `src/test/resources`:

```
application.key: value-common-test
```

...everything will stay the same, but `application.key` will be bound to `value-common-test` instead when you run the tests (for any profile). If you happen to just run the application, it will be bound to `value-common` instead.

Comment: If you redefine an application.yml under src/test/resources then you have to copy the whole content of file from src/main/resources/application.yml and then override properties for testing. If any new property comes in then you have to define it in both (main & test) application,yml file. Is it the right way to go?

Comment: You don't need to redefine everything, just the ones you would like to overwrite (plus the profile definitions, that should be the same, in case you want to take advantage of it). I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I didn't clear my point. Lets say I have a configuration property like "hystrix.enabled=true" in main application.yml. When I do some integration test and If have created my own application.yml in test/resources then I have to redefine the same property "hystrix.enabled=true" in my test application.yml as well to make my tests work. 
And if you have some beans whose creation depends on the evaluation of some custom properties defined in main application.yml (@Value(${aProperty}) then you have to copy all those properties in test application.yml as well to make tests work.

Comment: In my setup, I don't have to do any of that. I just have the main `application.yaml` with everything I need to run the application — isolated by profiles if needed. Then if I need a different value for a given set of properties to run the tests, I just place a single `application.properties` file with that one (or more) value(s) I want to overwrite under `src/test/resources`, keeping the rest (inherited from `application.yaml`) intact.

Comment: As far as I know if you have an `application.yml` under `src/test/resources` then the `application.yml` under `src/main/resources` is not read at all. I just tested that in my project. Therefore, I thought you can't inherit from from main `application.yml` under `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Try a YAML file in `main` and a `.properties` file in `test`. That's what I use. I will update the answer.